# How to use strtof endPointer?

Tags: c++

Looking at the examples presented by various google results, I don't really understand how the EndPtr works. For an example:

```
char szOrbits[] = "686.97 365.24";
char* pEnd;

float f1 = strtof (szOrbits, &pEnd);
```

The function takes the pointer of the pointer that is declared after the char array, does that mean that the actual type and contents of the pointer are irrelevant and the pointer is guaranteed to be allocated right after the array thus making its address the end point?

I tried using it like this:

```
ret.push_back(EquationPiece(strtof(&Source[mark], (char**)&Source[i])));
```

where ret is a vector, Source is a char array, mark is where the number begins and i is the next byte after the number but I'm getting some strange results. Is my usage incorrect or should I seek for the bug elsewhere?

Comment: Read this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/

Comment: @2501 That's the source of his example. So we can assume it didn't help to point to this site.

Comment: That use is incorrect. The pointer value for `endPtr` gets *stored* in the supplied location, so it must be the address of a `char *` variable.

Comment: The OP asked how to use the endPtr parameter of the function. She obviously did it wrong, that's the reason to ask. There is no seeking for debugger as the "put on hold" is claiming. So there is no need to include the desired behavior. Please read the question entirely before closing it even if it's wording is not so clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [the reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtof/) describes the parameter `pendptr` as a reference to a `char*` object this might be misundestood. In C we have only pointers and the second parameter of `strtof` is a pointer to a pointer to char.

You can utilize this parameter to get the point in the input char array that could not be used to convert the char array to the output float. If the pointer points to a '\0' than the array has been converted entirely. If it points to something different you can start error handling or further processing of the char array.

You should never cast any pointer when you are not sure what it means. Cast tells the compiler that the programmer knows it better. Depending on the meaning of your `EquationPiece` it might be useful to pass the endPtr:

```
ret.push_back(EquationPiece(strtof(&Source[mark], pEnd));
```

Comment: oh so its output not input, saves me from measuring the float in the first place I guess.